# Need an Algorithm to generate Serialnumber

Tags: algorithm, random, code-generation, generator, probability

I want to generate 16-digits hexadecimal serial-number like: F204-8BE2-17A2-CFF3.

(This pattern give me 16^16 distinct serial-number But I don't need all of them)

I need you all to suggest me an algorithm to generate these serial-numbers **randomly** with an special characteristic which is: 
**each two serial-numbers have (at-least) 6 different digits**

(= It means if you are given two most similar serial-number, they should still have difference in 6 indexes)

I know that a good algorithm with this characteristic needs to remember previously generated serial-numbers and I don't want that much.

**In fact, I need an algorithm which do this with least probability for a chosen pair to collide (less than 0.001 seems sufficient )**

**PS:**
I've just tried to create 10K string randomly using MD5 hash and It gave similar string( similar=more than 3 same digits) with 0.00018 probability.

Comment: "with least probability of bad serial-number (less than 0.001 seems sufficient" It all depends on the number of serial numbers you need. If you need 16^16 + 1 of them, you will certainly have at least one complete collision.

Comment: I need at most 1M serial number which is too less than 16^16

Comment: What do you mean by `0.001` probabilty? Probability for a chosen pair to collide or probability there is *some* pair that collides?

Comment: @NiklasB.Probability for a chosen pair to collide

Comment: Then you can just do the naive approach (see my answer)

Comment: See Eric Lippert's blog entry about using a [multiplicative inverse](http://ericlippert.com/2013/11/14/a-practical-use-of-multiplicative-inverses/) to generate random-looking sequential keys. That's a much simpler method than my technique of [Obfuscating sequential keys](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=839). The point to both, though, is that you can make your keys equal to 0, 6, 12, 18, etc., and then obfuscate them.

Comment: Thanks. I will read it soon.

Comment: @Jim: The problem here is to find a deterministic, unpredictable sequence of serial numbers with low probability of collision, not to generate that sequence in a pseudorandom order. Can you shed some light on how you would use the idea in the context of this problem?

Comment: @Niklas: Both of the approaches I mention generate a deterministic, *predictable* sequence of serial numbers where the probability of collision is exactly 0. The generated numbers are then obfuscated so that they appear random/unpredictable. The obfuscation is a one-to-one mapping. The result is the same: serial numbers that look random. They *could be* predicted, provided that somebody got known sequentially-generated keys and took the time to reverse-engineer the algorithm. But then, the same thing would be possible (perhaps a little more difficult) if the values were generated with a PRNG.

Comment: @NiklasB. That said, my method can't guarantee that there will be six digit differences in any two generated keys. So it's probably not a very good suggestion. I misunderstood his "six different digits" restriction at first reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to construct a correct generator without having to remember all previously generated codes. You can generate serial numbers that are spaced 6 characters apart by using [Hamming code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_code). A hamming code can be designed to arbitrarily space out two distinct generated values. Obviously, the greater the distance, the higher redundancy you will have to use, resulting in more complex code and longer numbers.

First you design a hamming code to your liking, that encodes a number into a sequence of hexadecimal digits and then you can take any sequence of numbers and use it as a seed, such as prime numbers. You just always need to remember, what number was used last and use the next one.

That being said, if you don't need to properly ensure minimal distance of two serials, and would settle for a small error, I would suggest that any half decent hash function or cypher should produce decently spaced out outputs. Therefore the first thing I would try to do is to take [MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) or [SHA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) hashes and test-drive them on numbers 1 - 1000. My hopes are, the results will be quite satisfactory.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look into the ANSI X9.17 pseudorandom bit generator. An algorithmic sketch is given in these [slides](http://people.scs.carleton.ca/~maheshwa/courses/4109/Seminar11/Pseudorandom_number_generation_QiuliangTang_revision.pdf). ANSI X9.17 generates 64-bit pseudorandom strings which is what you want.

A revised and enhanced version of this generator was approved by NIST. Please have a look at this [page](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/random_number.html).

Now whether you use ANSI X9.17 generator, another generator, or develop your own, it's a good idea to have the generator pass some statistical tests in order to ensure the quality of its pseudorandom bits.

Example tests include the [ENT battery](http://ftp.fourmilab.ch/random/), the [DIEHARD battery](http://www.stat.fsu.edu/pub/diehard/), and the [NIST battery](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/rng/documentation_software.html).

Comment: Good. I will test this too.